# Decimal To Binary Python Getting an Extra Zero In Return String

Tags: python, recursion, binary

This is for a school project. I need to create a function using recursion to convert an integer to binary string. It must be a str returned, not an int. The base case is n==0, and then 0 would need to be returned. There must be a base case like this, but this is where I think I am getting the extra 0 from (I could be wrong). I am using Python 3.6 with the IDLE and the shell to execute it.

The function works just fine, expect for this additional zero that I need gone.

Here is my function, dtobr:

```
def dtobr(n):
    """
    (int) -> (str)
    This function has the parameter n, which is a non-negative integer, 
    and it will return the string of 0/1's
    which is the binary representation of n. No side effects. 
    Returns bianry string as mentioned. This is like the function
    dtob (decimal to bianary) but this is using recursion. 

    Examples:

    >>> dtob(27)
    '11011'
    >>> dtob(0)
    '0'
    >>> dtob(1)
    '1'
    >>> dtob(2)
    '10'
    """
    if n == 0:
        return str(0)
    return dtobr(n // 2) + str(n % 2)
```

This came from the function I already wrote which converted it just fine, but without recursion. For reference, I will include this code as well, but this is not what I need for this project, and there are no errors with this:

```
 def dtob(n):
    """
    (int) -> (str)

    This function has the parameter n, which is a non-negative integer, 
    and it will return the string of 0/1's
    which is the binary representation of n. No side effects. 
    Returns bianry string as mentioned.

    Examples:

    >>> dtob(27)
    '11011'
    >>> dtob(0)
    '0'
    >>> dtob(1)
    '1'
    >>> dtob(2)
    '10'
    """
    string = ""
    if n == 0:
        return str(0)
    while n > 0:
        remainder = n % 2
        string = str(remainder) + string
        n = n // 2
```

Hopefully someone can help me get ride of that additional left hand zero. Thanks!

Comment: A good way to debug something like this is to put a print statement inside your function. If you printed `n` in each iteration, you'd see that you're hitting the `n==0` condition at the end every time. You need to change your conditional to account for the case when `n==1`. An easy thing is to do `if n <= 1: return(str(n))` instead of the `if n==0` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the condition to recursively handle both the `n // 2` and `n % 2`:

```
if n <= 1:
    return str(n)   # per @pault's suggestion, only needed str(n) instead of str(n % 2)
else:
    return dtobr(n // 2) + dtobr(n % 2)
```

Test case:

```
for i in [0, 1, 2, 27]:
    print(dtobr(i))

# 0
# 1
# 10
# 11011
```

FYI you can easily convert to binary format like so:

```
'{0:b}'.format(x)   # where x is your number
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to give you a thumbs up, but I am not able to yet with my account, so here is a virtual thumbs up :D

Comment: If you find this helpful, you can choose to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  It is by no means mandatory but can help highlight the answer helps resolves the issue for future visitors.

Comment: Can simplify `str(n%2)` as it's equivalent to `str(n)` for `n<=1`

Answer (score 0):

Since there is already an answer that points and resolves the issue with recursive way, lets see some interesting ways to achieve same goal.

Lets define a generator that will give us iterative way of getting binary numbers.

```
def to_binary(n):
    if n == 0: yield "0"
    while n > 0:
        yield str(n % 2)
        n = n / 2
```

Then you can use this iterable to get decimal to binary conversion in multiple ways.

Example 1.

`reduce` function is used to concatenate chars received from `to_binary` iterable (generator).

```
from functools import reduce

def to_binary(n):
    if n == 0: yield "0"
    while n > 0:
        yield str(n % 2)
        n = n / 2

print reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, to_binary(0)) # 0
print reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, to_binary(15)) # 1111
print reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, to_binary(15)) # 11011
```

Example 2.

`join` takes iterable, unrolls it and joins them by `''`

```
def to_binary(n):
    if n == 0: yield "0"
    while n > 0:
        yield str(n % 2)
        n = n / 2


print ''.join(to_binary(0)) # 0
print ''.join(to_binary(1)) # 1
print ''.join(to_binary(15)) # 1111
print ''.join(to_binary(27)) # 11011
```